# Configure gcc-4.8.5 to include GLIBCXX_3.4.20 on centos6

Tags: node.js, centos, gcc4.8, nodegit

Hi folks i've been searching for solutions to this problem for days but none of the methods posted online worked for me. Basically I'm trying to install [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/) library on my production server (`centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`). Doing `npm install` throws the following error:

```
Error: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/app/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node)
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c node /home/app/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js' }
```

Doing `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`  gives:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` is missing. Running `gcc -v`  gives:

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/packages/encap/gcc-4.8.5/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.5/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-shared --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-tls --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-libelf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC)
```

Some places suggest I install gcc-4.9 following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/834862/how-to-install-g-4-9-2-in-cent-os-6-5) . But it simply doesn't work because in the production server I have to install gcc through a host management tool(Roller) which is a pain in the ass and I want to avoid doing that.

Do you folks know any ways of getting the GLIBCXX_3.4.20 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` was added in GCC-4.9 ([reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)).

> Some places suggest I install gcc-4.9 following this . But it simply doesn't work because in the production server I have to install gcc through a host management tool(Roller) which is a pain in the ass and I want to avoid doing that.

Somehow, you **must** get `libstdc++.so.6` from `GCC-4.9.x` (or later) onto the production server, and in a place where your binary will find it.

If you don't want to use Roller, do it *any other way you like*.